# WCF service returning JSON with an anonymous object

Tags: c#, wcf, json, dynamic, return-type

For a simple API I am building I am using a couple of techniques. First of all, this is not my first API I am creating, but it is the first where I have combination of WCF, json and anonymous objects.

I got the following interface for the WCF API:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAPI
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ServiceResponse Authenticate(string username, string hashedPassword);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ServiceResponse GetProducts();
}
```

It's all pretty simple, just 2 methods I want to have working. The `ServiceResponse` class you see there is also really simple, but causing the problems I think:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public ResponseCode Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I made this class, so I can always send a Status (Simple int enum) and an object, for example a string or a list of objects.

I created a small script using jQuery to test my service, and the `Authenticate` method works like it should, but this method returns a `ServiceResponse` object, with just a 0 in the `Status` field. The `Value` field is left empty here.

The `GetProducts` method is the one where it gets tricky, an array of anonymous objects like this:

```
public ServiceResponse GetProducts()
{
       DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
       var results = from p in db.Products
                     where p.UserID == 1
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = p.ID,
                         Name = p.DecryptedName
                     };

        return ServiceResponse.OK(results.ToArray());
}
```

I am using an anonymous type object here, because I do not want to create proxy classes for all the classes I want to use in the API.

When I try out this code, with my simple jQuery script, FireBug tells me that my request has been aborted. I guess this is because of an Error 500 or something. When I put a breakpoint in my `GetProducts` method, it gets hit 7 times before Firefox says it is aborted and the script is fully run.

Here is the jQuery script I use to test out my WCF service:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Handlers/API.svc/GetProducts",
    data: '{}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var test = inspect(response, 5);
        $("#output").html(test);
    },
    error: function (message) {
        $("#output").html(inspect(message, 5));
    }
});
```

The `inspect` method you see in there, is just a small JS script that shows me the contents of an object.

I tried the following things to get it moving:

- Replace the anonymous objects with objects of the type `Product`, but this failed in the same way
- Return a `List<T>` instead of an array, but no luck there either.
- Returning without anything assigned to the `Value` property, this worked
- Changing the property `Value` to the `dynamic` type, this failed also

I would love it if I could use WCF to return some sort of array of anonymous objects, because that saves me creating 30+ proxy classes.

**NOTE**: The `Product` class is a class generated by LINQ. I am using C# 4.0 for this.

Comment: It's been a while since I played with LINQ, but the part where you create those anonymous objects - can't you convert those to `Dictionary<String, object>` ?

Comment: Not sure why you have 'data: {}' since you are not sending any data.  What happens when you remove it?

Comment: Removing it does not solve it either. I tried it without the data parameter and even added a parameter just to check if that would change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I believe that WCF is fairly strict and will not allow you to return an object the way you are trying to. If you know that the data is going to be an array every time you could change your definition to reflect that (but it sounds like this is not going to work in your case). Otherwise, you might want to consider changing your signature to a simple string and serializing the data into JSON first before returning it.

Comment: Serializing it in a string is indeed an option, takes a bit of beauty away though. Indeed, the Value field is not always an array, I want it to keep anything I need. I am also thinking about converting it to a normal ASMX webservice, just to see if I can pull it off that way. Thanks for your answer, but I thought WCF would accept the dynamic return type.

Comment: Converted it to a normal webservice and I can return dynamic types without a problem. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. You have to use web services instead or -as you said- use a proxy class.